# Layout styles in android

Tags: android, android-layout

i want to create screen in android like the image below(click on the hyperlink) but i am not getting the idea that how to create this screen just provide me solution for my problem.[click to see image](http://cdn2.staztic.com/screenshots/219871-2.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with sahhhm on the ListView. In addition, to display the cinema info you will need a custom list-item view which is going to contain an image view to display the left-hand image, four different text views to display the text and another image view for the right-hand image. You'll also have to accommodate the location in a view and the control bar at the top is possibly a custom control displayed in an activity which has the attribute android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" in the android manifest file so that the title bar is not shown.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to take a look at [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html). Here are a couple of basic tutorials ([Android Developer Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html) and [Android People Tutorial](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-listview-example/)) that will help get you started. Afterwards, you should be able to search for and find more specific examples of what you want.