# Android List view

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create the activity which will load the images from Web by using urls and i want to load that images in list view and i want some specific text and properties of that image in front of that image like the image below [Click to see Image](http://cdn2.staztic.com/screenshots/219871-2.jpg).Is there any way to store that images temporarily in phones memory.So how can i do this activity please give me perfect solution so that i can complete my application.How can i load the images from web.

Comment: Repost of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4536890/layout-styles-in-android/4536919#4536919

Comment: Show us what you have.... i'm not writing the entire application for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try like this

URL img_value=new URL(img[position]);

```
               Bitmap mIcon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(img_value.openConnection().getInputStream());

                holder.image.setImageBitmap(mIcon1);
```

here holder.image is an image widget kept in your xml for image view.

It directy load an image from the given url.
or else try like this below by creating class named DrawableManager...

new DrawableManager().fetchDrawableOnThread(VAL3[position],holder.icon);

```
package com.fsp.demo;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.lang.ref.SoftReference;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class DrawableManager {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private final Map drawableMap;

    public DrawableManager() {
        drawableMap = new HashMap<String, SoftReference<Drawable>>();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Drawable fetchDrawable(String urlString) {
        SoftReference<Drawable> drawableRef = (SoftReference<Drawable>) drawableMap
                .get(urlString);
        if (drawableRef != null) {
            Drawable drawable = drawableRef.get();
            if (drawable != null)
                return drawable;
            // Reference has expired so remove the key from drawableMap
            drawableMap.remove(urlString);
        }

        if (Constants.LOGGING)
            Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "image url:" + urlString);
        try {
            InputStream is = fetch(urlString);
            Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
            drawableRef = new SoftReference<Drawable>(drawable);
            drawableMap.put(urlString, drawableRef);
            if (Constants.LOGGING)
                Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(),
                        "got a thumbnail drawable: " + drawable.getBounds()
                                + ", " + drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() + ","
                                + drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() + ", "
                                + drawable.getMinimumHeight() + ","
                                + drawable.getMinimumWidth());
            return drawableRef.get();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            if (Constants.LOGGING)
                Log.e(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "fetchDrawable failed",
                        e);
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            if (Constants.LOGGING)
                Log.e(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "fetchDrawable failed",
                        e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void fetchDrawableOnThread(final String urlString,
            final ImageView imageView) {
//      Log.v("Drawable_url",urlString);
        SoftReference<Drawable> drawableRef = (SoftReference<Drawable>) drawableMap
                .get(urlString);
        if (drawableRef != null) {
            Drawable drawable = drawableRef.get();
            if (drawable != null) {
                imageView.setImageDrawable(drawableRef.get());
                return;
            }
            // Reference has expired so remove the key from drawableMap
            drawableMap.remove(urlString);
        }

        final Handler handler = new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(Message message) {
                imageView.setImageDrawable((Drawable) message.obj);
            }
        };

        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO : set imageView to a "pending" image
                Drawable drawable = fetchDrawable(urlString);
                Message message = handler.obtainMessage(1, drawable);
                handler.sendMessage(message);
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }

    private InputStream fetch(String urlString) throws MalformedURLException,
            IOException {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(urlString);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
        return response.getEntity().getContent();
    }

}
```